# PHP: Function to group object array by objects element

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a multi-dimensional array.i want to group this array by brand_id and cat_id. In the following array  [0],[1] and [2],[3]  have similar brand_ids and cat_ids.i want to remove product_ids and want get sum of qtys in that object.

```
 Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
        [brand_id] => 1 
        [cat_id] => 1 
        [qty] => 150 
        [product_id] => 1 
         ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
        [brand_id] => 1 
        [cat_id] => 1 
        [qty] => 250 
        [product_id] => 5
        ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object 
        (
        [brand_id] => 4 
        [cat_id] => 35 
        [qty] => 100 
        [product_id] => 322 
         ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
        [brand_id] => 4 
        [cat_id] => 35
        [qty] => 200 
        [product_id] => 321 
        ) 
        )
```

i want to rearrange array like this

```
  Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object 
            ( 
            [brand_id] => 1 
            [cat_id] => 1 
            [qty] => 400
             ) 

            [1] => stdClass Object 
            (
            [brand_id] => 4 
            [cat_id] => 35 
            [qty] => 300 
            [product_id] => 322 
             ) 
             )
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the query that created this array rather than fiddling with its results

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: @ceadreak `usort` is for reordering an array, it doesn't merge elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 2-dimensional associative array whose keys are the `brand_id` and `cat_id`, and values are the objects with the `qty` property containing the total quantity.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($products as $p) {
    if (isset($result[$p->brand_id][$p->cat_id])) {
        $result[$p->brand_id][$p->cat_id]->qty += $p->qty;
    } else {
        $clone = clone $p;
        unset ($clone->product_id);
        $result[$p->brand_id][$p->cat_id] = $clone;
    }
}
```

You can then flatten the array with `array_walk_recursive`.

```
$return = array();
array_walk_recursive($result, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
```

I got that code from [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)